# Get base64 image using Retrofit error com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to download an Image from a authenticated site. the site returns a base64 version of image. is this the right way to do it on retrofit? how do get the image and set to my image view.

```
    @GET("/img/avatars/{id}")
    public void getProfilePic(@Path("id") int id,
                          Callback<TypedByteArray> result);
```

i set my restadapter logging to full and the response value looks like this

```
���V�3��Ωw���Tw�5�vT��>8u�`�j�S�������#���%�A���"Xw��Oq������G@]éG���f�~A#lD�)<���•
```

not the base64 string.

What I have tried

```
customResAdapter(ImageService.class).getProfilePic(id, new Callback<TypedByteArray>() {
            @Override
            public void success(TypedByteArray result, Response response) { 
                try {
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(result.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                } 
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) { 
            }
        });
```

i dont know if the following codes are right but currently i get this error message

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path

Comment: you need to decode base64 string to bitmap, `byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);`

Comment: It looks like you are logging a byte array after converting it into utf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `GsonConverter` you will always end up in `JsonParseException`. You need to subclass GsonConverter and avoid `JsonParseExceptions` and proceed with handling the `Response` itself.

Validating Json response in your subclassed `Converter` will give you hint how to handle the deserialization.
In other words, if is valid json you pipeline it to `GsonConverter`, otherwise decode it from Base64.

```
public class TypedByteArrayConverter extends GsonConverter {
    public TypedByteArrayConverter(Gson gson) {
        super(gson);
    }

    public TypedByteArrayConverter(Gson gson, String charset) {
        super(gson, charset);
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException {
        //if you are trying to deserialize POJO from json, make a supercall, otherwise convert to TypedByteArray
        if(!type.getClass().isAssignableFrom(TypedByteArray.class)) {
           return super.fromBody(body, type);
        }else {
            try {
                long length = body.length();
                ByteString base64 = ByteString.read(body.in(), (int) length);
                return new TypedByteArray(body.mimeType(), base64.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`ByteString` is from [Okio](http://square.github.io/okio/) package

However, image loading with Retrofit is rather strange idea.