# Receiving a PDF response from server with retrofit

Tags: android, http, pdf, retrofit

I've a view that generates an PDF document. It's works fine at the browsers (desktop), but my final objective is to deliver it over an android application.

Right now i'm using the retrofit library to handle my requests/responses (only json).

My problem is the data type I need to pass on the `Callback<>` to handle/receive the PDF data and then save it to the disk?

Comment: Retrofit is designed for talking to Web services. If you have a URL that is just a document (e.g., PDF), I would use something else to download it (e.g., OkHttp, `HttpURLConnection`).

Comment: CommonsWear is right, but you can try to tweak it by writing custom converter that will return `TypedByteArray` See this, with slight modification you can achieve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165438/get-base64-image-using-retrofit-error-com-google-gson-jsonsyntaxexception-java/28186334#28186334

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski ok, this is almost what i want. I dont think i need to parse it to a TypedByteArray, but i will test. The other problem is how can i set it as a custom converter? I know there is a method called **setConverter** and it accepts the instance of the Converter, but the code you link show no empty constructor. So how can i set?

Comment: @vyscond  You set it in your `RestAdapter.Builder` with `setConverter()` method.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski yes, but extending from **GsonConvert** makes my custom converter class do not receive empty constructor. so need to pass a (at least) one **Gson** object. I'm passing like this `RestAdapter.Build.setConverter(new MyConverter(new Gson()))...` but when i send the request the server is not receiving.

Comment: @vyscond Have you tried to just override toBody() method from the converter and assure that super class method is called?

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski yes. i did, put it's being called.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski sorry man, i just forgot to adjust the string address (nothing about the converter). My bad.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can you post your converter?

Comment: Yes. Maybe. You tried to make one too?

Answer (score 3):

For everyone wondering a human way to do that here is my workflow:

1 - After Generating the PDF file grab the bytes and convert it to base64 string.

I can easily do that with python using [**pyfpdf**](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf) lib and using Django as back-end:

```
import base64

def my_view(request):
    pdf = MyCustomPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_margins(12,3,3)
    pdf.render() # PDF is ready to be saved
    b = pdf.output('output.pdf','B') # got the PDF as a byte array
    return JsonResponse(
        {  
            "name" : "my_doc.pdf",
            "content64" : base64.b64encode(b).decode('utf8')
        }
    )
```

*remember this example can be done with other backends/libs!*

2 - On you Android project set a **string** field on the model you want to use to receive the PDF response/callback. So our PDF will arrive like this.

```
{  
    "name" : "my_doc.pdf",
    "content64" : "aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ="
}
```

So on Java we can set a custom POJO

```
class PDF{
    private String name;
    private String content64;

    // (...)
}
```

3 - The base64 will be a simple **string**! To get the real file as bytes just write a routine like this

```
class PDF{
    private String name;
    private String content64;

    // (...)

    public byte[] content64AsByteArray(){ // Helps you convert string to byte formats :B
        return Base64.decode(content64,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public String save(String path) {

        try {

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + path;

            File f1 = new File(path);

            OutputStream out = null;
            out = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + this.name);
            out.write(this.content64AsByteArray());
            out.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return this.path; // I like to return it because i can use it to start a "open file" intent
    }
}
```

4 - the receive callback would be like this with the retrofit

```
pdfCallback = new Callback<PDF>() {

    @Override public void success(PDF pdf, Response response) {

        if (response.getStatus() == 200) {

            String pathToPDF = pdf.save() // save PDF

        }

    }

    @Override public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        (...)
    }
}

MyAPI.callbacks.getPDF( (...), pdfCallback);
```